# creating a variable with NA becoming 0 if at least one of the components is not NA

Tags: r, database

Imagine I have three variables, want to create a fourth variable called Total that it is the sum of A, B, and C but.... if missing values (NA) appears on 1 or 2 of the variables but not in the three of them together they become 0. As presented in the example below (last row)

```
A  B  C Total
10 10 10 30
NA NA NA NA
10 NA NA 10
```

So far I have:

```
data$Total <- A + B + C
```

Cheers

Comment: `data$Total <- rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: Be advised that NA != 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data$Total2 <- rowSums(data[, c("A", "B", "C")])
data$Total2[rowSums(is.na(data[, c("A", "B", "C")])) %in% 1:2] <- 0
data
   A  B  C Total Total2
1 10 10 10    30     30
2 NA NA NA    NA     NA
3 10 NA NA    10      0
```

Maybe I misunderstood the requirements and the already specified `Total` is the hoped-for output. In that case:

```
data$Total3 <- rowSums(data[, c("A", "B", "C")], na.rm = TRUE)
data$Total3[rowSums(is.na(data[, c("A", "B", "C")])) == 3] <- NA
data
   A  B  C Total Total2 Total3
1 10 10 10    30     30     30
2 NA NA NA    NA     NA     NA
3 10 NA NA    10      0     10
```

Comment: Hi @Snoram, thanks for your answer. I indeed need only one variable called Total whose results are the ones from your Total and Total3. When I run your latest code for Total3 I still obtain NA for the third variable

Comment: I just ran the code again from scratch and got the same results... that is, I didn't get NA for the third row.

Comment: stupid mistake I was doing, code works great. Thanks!